# Angular Karma Test getting “TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function”

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

> Controller

```
dashboardApp.controller('ExecutiveController', ['$scope',   'ExecutiveService',
function ($scope, executiveService) {

    executiveService.getDashboardData().then(
    function success(response) {
        $scope.productsInfo = response.data;
    }, function error(reason) {
        console.log(reason);
    });

} ]);
```

> Test case for Controller
>       'use strict';

```
describe('ExecutiveController', function () {
var scope, ctrl, mockService, $timeout;

beforeEach(module('do.dashboard'));

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $q, _$timeout_) {

    mockService = jasmine.createSpyObj('ExecutiveService', ['getDashboardData']);
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $timeout = _$timeout_;
    mockService.getDashboardData.andReturn($q.when(

        [{Products:{Name:'Resource ',measure:'59',Work:'60'}}]

    ));

    ctrl = $controller('ExecutiveController', {
        $scope: scope,
        ExecutiveService: mockService,

    });
}));


it('controller should not be null', function () {
    expect(ctrl).not.toBe(null);
});


it('should call the service method and set the scope data', function () {
    expect(mockService.getDashboardData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    $timeout.flush();
    expect(scope.productsInfo.Products.Name).toEqual('Resource');
    expect(scope.productsInfo.products.measure).toEqual(59);


});

});
```

> Here when i run it in karma runner it shows error as Angular Karma Test getting “TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function”  and it gives the message which is present in the it method

Comment: Which `it` function throws the error? Can you add the actual error message?

Comment: Also which version of jasmine are you using? The syntax changed in 2.0, so you should be using `mockService.getDashboardData.and.returnValue` not `mockService.getDashboardData.andReturn`

Comment: Actually every its methodshows error

Comment: Chrome 40.0.2214 (Windows 7) ExecutiveController controller should not be null F
AILED
        TypeError: undefined is not a function
            at Object.<anonymous> (C:/EngineeringExcellence_New/test/unit/Execut
iveControllerSpec.js:13:38)
            at Object.e [as invoke] (C:/EngineeringExcellence_New/app/js/vendor/
angular.min.js:37:19)
            at Object.workFn (C:/EngineeringExcellence_New/test/lib/angular/angu
lar-mock.js:2341:34)
        Error: Declaration Location

Comment: ExecutiveController controller should not be null FAILED TypeError: undefined is not a function at Object.<anonymous> (C:/EngineeringExcellence_New/test/unit/ExecutiveControllerSpec.js:13:42)at Object.e [as invoke(C:/EngineeringExcellence_New/app/js/vendor/
angular.min.js:37:19)
            at Object.workFn (C:/EngineeringExcellence_New/test/lib/angular/angu
lar-mock.js:2341:34)
Error: Declaration Location at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (C:/EngineeringExcellence_New/test/lib/angular/angular-mock.js:2312:33)at Suite.<anonymous>

Comment: You need to thoroughly check your test code first. There are several typos that are causing issues.

Comment: Can you show your conf.js ? I had the same errors and found out that I had to add some js files in the conf to bring it to work

Comment: module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({basePath: '',
 frameworks: ['jasmine'],
files: [
      'app/js/vendor/angular.min.js',
      'app/js/vendor/angular-*.js',
      'test/lib/angular/angular-mock.js',
      'test/lib/*.js',
      'app/js/vendor/underscore-min.js',
      'app/executive-summary/app.js',
      'app/executive-summary/*.js',
      'test/unit/*.js'
    ],
exclude: [
    ],
 preprocessors: {
    },
 reporters: ['progress'],
 port: 9876,
colors: true,
autoWatch: true,
singleRun: false
  });
};

Comment: please edit your post and add the config.js there and not in a comment

Comment: its not getting added for now error in submit so will update it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong syntax for Jasmine 2.0 - it should be

`mockService.getDashboardData.and.returnValue`

not

`mockService.getDashboardData.andReturn`

http://jsfiddle.net/xqa41at0/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72416/discussion-on-answer-by-james-angular-karma-test-getting-typeerror-undefined).

Comment: @bluefeet The old site used to prompt and give a link to chat. Is that no longer a feature? I would have done earlier, but i'm not sure how you explicitly move from an issue to chat?

Comment: You might not have received a notification because the user technically doesn't have enough rep to chat. But if a moderator moves the comments, then the user can join.

Comment: Thanks for the help